# Expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 1, 150, 75, 3)?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, dqn

similar problems to this have been posted and answered on this forum but this particular case I didn't find any solution. ( I'm using Keras )

I have images of the shape `(150,75,3)` and I reshaped the numpy array to `(1,150,75,3)`

This is supposed to work but this error comes out:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 1, 150, 75, 3)
```

EDIT : this is how I process the image :

```
self.pinballEnvironmrnt = PinballEnv(self.screenDimensions,self.startPosition)
    image = pygame.surfarray.array3d(self.pinballEnvironmrnt.screen)
    #image = Image.fromarray(image)
    #image = image.resize(self.resize)
    self.state = numpy.array([image])#.reshape((-1,1200,600,3))
    print('the shape of the state ------------------> ',self.state.shape)
```

output ( error not included in this pic):
[image]
and this is the DQN agent :

```
pool_size = (2, 2)
    # MODEL 1
    self.model = Sequential()
    self.model.add(Conv2D(4, (3, 3),input_shape=(150,75,3),activation='relu'))
    # Conv Layer 2
    self.model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3),activation='relu'))
    # Pooling 1
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))

    self.model.add(Flatten())
    self.model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(Dense(actions,activation='linear'))
    print(self.model.summary())
```

Comment: Please add the code where you create your input and define your model, otherwise there only be some random guess.

Comment: ok i added the code , i hope the problem is more clear now

Comment: Still unclear. The error raise when you are feeding input to the `model.fit()`. So, you should add this line. Also `model.compile()` and where you exactly define and reshape your input. You have added some codes which reshapes an array to `(1,1200,600,3)`, but your error is about an array with shape `(1,150,75,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have given too many dimensions as input to the `Conv2D` layer. Consider that images are represented in NumPy as matrices of shape `(height, width, channels)`. In general, when dealing with images, machine learning libraries expect as inputs batches of data, so the actual input shape should be `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`, and that's why the error says that the expected dimensions are 4. Practically, if you have a variable `images` which is a list of all your images, then the batch dimension could be added like `np.array(images)` or `tf.convert_to_tensor(images)` if you use tensorflow.

Comment: I should also add that if you only have a single image to feed to the model, then it should first be inserted into a list, like this: `np.array([image])` or `tf.convert_to_tensor([image])`.

Comment: i added more code to make the problem clearer